# Any way possible to make live usb come with usable default settings and programs

Tags: live-usb

Persistent usb stick is unusable slow. Takes 5 minutes to boot up, programs take half an hour to install. Even clicking search links in google takes a while to load. unusable. But I can boot to live usb mode where everything loads and installs quickly.

Is it possible to edit the live usb so it comes with basic stuff so I don't need to reinstall everything everytime? Like different web browser, adblock, correct keyboard layout and language, ffmpg addon etc.. That would be there bu default? I know it still is not persistent but at least I don't need to reinstall everything everytime I reboot and it is usable quick.

I am complete noob with linux so be as condescendingly basic as you can.

Comment: cubic is the one you are looking for.. https://launchpad.net/cubic